# Ссылка на строку не ссылается на экземпляр String

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Есть код:

```
internal static void Run(string task, RichTextBox output)
{
        string path = Path.GetFullPath("Project");
        Console.WriteLine($"/c cd \"{path}\" & jppm {task}");
        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        p.StartInfo.Arguments = $"/c cd \"{path}\" & jppm {task}";
        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        p.Start();
        string line = null;
        while((line = p.StandardOutput.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            byte[] bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(p.StandardOutput.ReadLine());
            string result = Encoding.GetEncoding("cp866").GetString(bytes);
            output.Document.Blocks.Add(new Paragraph(new Run(result)));
        }
 }
```

Строка: `Console.WriteLine($"/c cd \"{path}\" & jppm {task}");` выводит:
*`/c cd "C:\Users\deadmoz5er\source\repos\IDE\IDE\bin\Debug\Project" & jppm app:run`*
Если эту команду я выполню в CMD в ручную, то все ок, но Visual Studio кидает ошибку:

*Вызвано исключение: "System.ArgumentNullException" в mscorlib.dll
Необработанное исключение типа "System.ArgumentNullException" в mscorlib.dll
Ссылка на строку не ссылается на экземпляр String.*

Ошибка в строке:
`byte[] bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(p.StandardOutput.ReadLine());`

Как решить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
byte[] bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(line);
```

Answer (score 0):

**[РЕШЕНО]**

Код:

```
internal static void Run(string task, RichTextBox output)
{
        string path = Path.GetFullPath("Project");
        Console.WriteLine("/c cd \"{path}\" & jppm {task}");
        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        p.StartInfo.Arguments = $"/c cd \"{path}\" & jppm {task}";
        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        p.Start();
        string line = "";
        while((line = p.StandardOutput.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            byte[] bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(line);
            string result = Encoding.GetEncoding("cp866").GetString(bytes);
            output.Document.Blocks.Add(new Paragraph(new Run(result)));
        }
}
```